# Sum particular column of random text data

Tags: python-3.x

I have following data:

```
————-
My Chart
————-

Summary
—————————
Name        Count Charges           Dont Count these
joe         20.00 US                0.00 US
def         400.00 US               20.00 US
ken         1000.00 US              0.00 US
dan         200.00 US               0.00 US

More Usage
——————————
Name    Type            Usage
Jen     fun         104.00
Jim     fun         200.00
….
```

I am trying to get a count of all charges under "Count Charges" column, is there an easier way to get that value without looping through all values? I looked into pandas but not able to load data to it. I tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(usage_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a tab separated file that could easily be inserted into a database then you could call sum(countCharges) to get the total

Comment: I am creating a python script, where will database fit in this picture?